# Vetur does not work properly in template(not checking data, method...)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vetur

I'm using the vetur extension of the vscode in my vue project with typescript. I just found out that vetur can actually check inside template tag for my prop, method... and even type checking for the variable. But in my case, it does nothing, no type check, no valid name-checking, no hover information (the thing I want the most). I wonder if there needs to be some setting for this to work.
Some information in my case :

- vscode version 1.49.0
- vetur version v0.27.3
- using vue v2.6.11 with vue-class-component

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who looking for the answer, i had to go to the setting json file and add

```
vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService: true
```

Comment: I know this question is old but just for reference:
https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/interpolation.html#generic-language-features